# Set One Custom message for multiple field in laravel form validation

Tags: validation, laravel-4

Let I have 3 fields in the form.

I write this code for form validation.

```
$rules = array(
                'field_1' => 'required',
                'field_2' => 'required',
                'field_3' => 'required',
            );


$messages = array(
                'field_1.required' => 'Please fill up all value',
                'field_2.required' => 'Please fill up all value',
                'field_3.required' => 'Please fill up all value',
            );

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);
```

Now if user fill up the form 2 fields with blank then the validator return two error message. If user fill up the form 3 fields with blank then the validator return three error message. But I want to show only one message for all fields.

Comment: So you want it to say "Some fields are empty" as in representing multiple fields or return one string of error messages as in "field 1 is empty, field 2 is empty" etc

Comment: Elaborate on "I want to show only one message for all fields"

Comment: @Brian Yes. You are right

Comment: Ok Im right, but about which of my scenarios :)

Comment: @Brian "Some fields are empty" are empty. But I want show this message Once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could change it to

```
$messages = array(
    'required' => 'Please fill up all value',
);
validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);
```

and let your view only output the first error message.

```
{{ $errors->first(null,'<div class="alert alert-danger">:message</div>') }}
```